# Display list items as grid with pages

Tags: html, angularjs, css

I'm at my wits end here... I've been looking for hours and hours... What I'm trying to do, is display a list of items as a grid layout view with pages (like Android home screen) meaning, the list items should be displayed in a fixed X times Y grid and the list should be split into (list.length / x*y) pages. I've been googling to find something that would help me achieve this, but I've failed to find anything... I've found that I could use angular-slick for the page navigation part, but haven't found anything to use to split and display the data... 
Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

simply you try to use bootstrap then you can solve grid system problem.

> [bootstrap gridsystem](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)